# Problemas com If Else Statement encadeados em C language

Tags: c, if, else

Eu estou iniciando na programação e tive bastante dificuldade pra entender o If Else de maneira encadeada. Me deparei com a seguinte situação, ao rodar o código apenas a primeira ou a segunda condição (If/Else) são possíveis de serem true, independente do valor

```
    float Peso, Altura, Imc;
    printf("----------- #17 -----------\n\n");
    printf("Para fazer o calculo do IMC, forneca seu peso: \n");
    scanf("%f", &Peso);
    printf("E sua altura? \n");
    scanf("%f", &Altura);
    printf("Seu peso e sua altura sao: %.2fKg, %.2fm\n\n",Peso, Altura);
    Imc = Peso/(Altura*Altura);
    printf("Seu IMC e: %.2f\n", Imc);
    if (Imc>=40.0)
    {
        printf("------------------------------\n");
        printf("Voce esta com Obesidade Grau III (morbida)\n");
        printf("------------------------------\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if(35.0<Imc<39.9)
                {
                    printf("------------------------------\n");
                    printf("Voce esta com Obesidade Grau II(severa)\n");
                    printf("------------------------------\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    if(30.0<Imc<34.9)
                            {
                                printf("------------------------------\n");
                                printf("Voce esta com Obesidade Grau I\n");
                                printf("------------------------------\n");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if(25.0<Imc<29.9)
                                        {
                                            printf("------------------------------\n");
                                            printf("Voce esta com excesso de peso\n");
                                            printf("------------------------------\n");
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            if(18.6<Imc<24.9)
                                                {
                                                    printf("------------------------------\n");
                                                    printf("Voce esta saudavel\n");
                                                    printf("------------------------------\n");
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    if(Imc<18.5)
                                                        {
                                                            printf("------------------------------\n");
                                                            printf("Voce esta abaixo do peso \n");
                                                            printf("------------------------------\n");
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        }
                            }
                }
    }

return 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se fizer o debug do programa vai verificar que `if(30.0<Imc<34.9)` é sempre true, ou seja, não é dessa forma que terá de fazer.

Em C tem de fazer a comparação desta forma:
 `if(Imc<34.9 && 30.0<Imc)`

---

Ou seja, `Imc` tem de ser menor que 34,9 `E` `Imc` tem de ser maior que 30.0.

Tem de editar todos os if's e colocar dessa forma.

Não confundir `&&` com `||`(`OU`) se fizer  `if(Imc<34.9 || 30.0<Imc)`
Significa que, `Imc` tem de ser menor que 34.9 OU `Imc` maior que 30.0

Se `Imc=5` a condição será verdadeira porque basta UMA delas ser verdadeira, neste caso `5<34.9`é verdadeiro

---

*(@hkotsubo)* Apenas para complementar, o operador `<` retorna o valor 1 se a comparação é verdadeira, e 0 se ela for falsa (veja a definição [aqui](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.8p6)). Assim sendo, `25.0 < Imc < 29.9` é interpretado como "o valor da expressão `25.0 < Imc` é menor que `29.9`?". Como a expressão `25.0 < Imc` pode retornar somente 1 ou zero, ela sempre será menor que `29.9`, portanto a expressão sempre será verdadeira.

Comment: Apenas para complementar, o operador `<` retorna o valor `1` se a comparação é verdadeira, e `0` se ela for falsa (veja a definição [aqui](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.8p6)). Assim sendo, `25.0 < Imc < 29.9` é interpretado como "o valor da expressão `25.0 < Imc` é menor que 29.9?". Como a expressão `25.0 < Imc` pode retornar somente 1 ou zero, ela sempre será menor que 29.9, portanto a expressão sempre será verdadeira. Já havia me esquecido que C tinha essas esquisitices... :-)

Comment: Irei editar e colocar isso, obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Vamos reorganizar e simplificar este código usando o maravilhoso `if else`:

```
float Peso, Altura, Imc;
printf("----------- #17 -----------\n\n");
printf("Para fazer o calculo do IMC, forneca seu peso: \n");
scanf("%f", &Peso);
printf("E sua altura? \n");
scanf("%f", &Altura);
printf("Seu peso e sua altura sao: %.2fKg, %.2fm\n\n",Peso, Altura);
Imc = Peso / (Altura * Altura);
printf("Seu IMC e: %.2f\n", Imc);
printf("------------------------------\n");
if (Imc >= 40) {
    printf("Voce esta com Obesidade Grau III (morbida)\n");
} else if (35 <= Imc && Imc < 40) {
    printf("Voce esta com Obesidade Grau II (severa)\n");
} else if (30 <= Imc && Imc < 35) {
    printf("Voce esta com Obesidade Grau I\n");
} else if (25 <= Imc && Imc < 30) {
    printf("Voce esta com excesso de peso\n");
} else if (18.5 <= Imc && Imc < 25) {
    printf("Voce esta saudavel\n");
} else if (Imc < 18.5) {
    printf("Voce esta abaixo do peso\n");
}
printf("------------------------------\n");
return 0;
```

Observe que as expressões são do tipo `(25 <= Imc && Imc < 30)`. Isso daí é bem diferente que `(25.0<Imc<29.9)`. Lembre-se alguém pode ter um IMC tal como 29.95, então é importante você prestar atenção onde usa o `<`, `<=`, `>`e `>=` para não deixar nenhuma lacuna nas condições por menor que seja.

Ainda dá para simplificar um pouco mais:

```
if (Imc >= 40) {
    printf("Voce esta com Obesidade Grau III (morbida)\n");
} else if (Imc >= 35) {
    printf("Voce esta com Obesidade Grau II (severa)\n");
} else if (Imc >= 30) {
    printf("Voce esta com Obesidade Grau I\n");
} else if (Imc >= 25) {
    printf("Voce esta com excesso de peso\n");
} else if (Imc >= 18.5) {
    printf("Voce esta saudavel\n");
} else {
    printf("Voce esta abaixo do peso\n");
}
```

Pois você pode se aproveitar do fato de que as condições dos `if`s anteriores não precisam ser retestadas nos posteriores. Por exemplo, se o teste do `Imc >= 40` falhou e caiu no `else`, então é óbvio que `Imc < 40` será sempre verdadeiro nesse caso e por isso nem precisa ser testado.